# Prove that $f(x)>f(y)$ if $x>y$

Tags: functions

I am working on Spivaks calculus book and have the following question:

We have a function with properties (Chapter 3, Ex. 17, (d)):
$$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$$
$$f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$$
and we are trying to prove that $f(x)=x$ for $x$ a real number.
In this step (d) we want to prove that $f(x)>f(y)$ if $x>y$ and here I am struggling.

My attempt was to do the following:
$x>y$ is the same as $x-y>0$.
Then
$$f(x-y) = f(x)+f(-y) = f(x)+f(-1)f(y)=f(x)+f(y)$$
because from (a) we know that
$$f(1)=1=f((-1)(-1))=f(-1)^2$$
therefore
$$f(-1)=1$$
From (c) we know that $f(x)>0 $ if $x>0$ so
$$f(x-y)=f(x)+f(y)>0$$
but i want $f(x)-f(y)>0$.
The solution manual says instantly $f(x-y)=f(x)-f(y)$, but why is that? And what is wrong in my reasoning?

Comment: $f^2(-1)=1$ implies $f(-1) = \pm 1$. If $f(x)$ was indeed the identity map, $f(-1)$ would be $-1$ and not $1$.

Comment: Oh yes you are right I forgot about the $-1$ solution. But I cannot assume that it is the identity map therefore I cannot use this argument I guess.

Comment: You can show, without knowing that $f$ is the identity, that $f(-1)=1$ would contradict the assumptions.

Comment: Oh yes I see because if $f(-1)=1=f(0-1)=f(0)-f(1)=0-1=-1$ a contradiction. I used  1. and 2. from the post below. Therefore $f(-1)=-1$

Comment: How did you get $f(0-1)=f(0)-f(1)$ from 1.? Shouldn't it be $f(0-1)=f(0)+f(-1)$?

Comment: Yes and then use 2. from the post below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ implies that:

1. $f(0)=0$ because $f(0)=f(0+0)=f(0)+f(0)$
2. $f(-x)=-f(x)$ because $0=f(0)=f(x-x)=f(x)+f(-x)$
3. $f(x-y)=f(x)-f(y)$ because $f(x-y)=f(x)+f(-y)=f(x)-f(y)$

These are classical properties of group homomorphisms.

---

There's something wrong with your reasoning though. $f(-1)^2=1$ implies that $f(-1)=\pm 1$ not $f(-1)=1$. And indeed, in reality it is $-1$, because ultimately $f(x)=x$ is supposed to be a solution, so $f(-1)=-1$. So either $f(x)=x$ is not a solution (spoiler alert: it actually is) or you've made a mistake.

Here's a different idea. First of all if $f(x_0)=0$ for some $x_0\neq 0$ then $f(x)=0$ for all $x$. That's because

$$f(x)=f(x_0x_0^{-1}x)=f(x_0)f(x_0^{-1}x)=0\cdot f(x_0^{-1}x)=0$$

Note that constant $0$ is a valid solution.

Now assume that $f$ is not constant $0$.

For any $x> 0$ we have

$$f(x)=f(\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x})=f(\sqrt{x})\cdot f(\sqrt{x})=f(\sqrt{x})^2\geq 0$$

But as we've said $f(x)$ cannot be equal $0$ because $f$ is not constant $0$. And so $f(x)>0$.

Therefore if $x> y$ then $x-y> 0$ and so $f(x-y)> 0$ meaning $f(x)-f(y)> 0$ which finally leads to $f(x)> f(y)$.

Comment: Thank you. You are right, I forgot about the $-1$ solution, therefore I cannot get to the solution with my idea I think. But your step 1. and 2. made it clear although I would not have came up myself with this reasoning!

Comment: The problem requires a bit of a cheat. Spivak's solution (which mirrors freakish's) depends on the existence of $\sqrt{x}$ for $x>0$. Fortunately, *that* existence is proven in the "Three Hard Theorems" chapter.